# Omnetpp wirelesshost sending useful information

Tags: omnet++, wireless, veins, inet

I am new to Omnetpp, and I am trying to send messages from one node to another wirelessly.
Basically, I would like to do something as in the tictoc example of Omnetpp (https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/) but then wirelessly.
I have installed INET already, and I have seen the wireless example, which uses the UdpBasicAPP. However, I do not know how to change the data of the message send while using the UdPBasicAPP. In my case, what I am sending (i.e. the data) is very important because it is part of a bigger project. Eventually, the idea is to use the 802.11p standard (which exists in VEINS) and multiple nodes, but I thought this was a good place to start.

I hope someone can help me out.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. just to be aware: 802.11p is also supported directly in INET. Just set the `opMode` parameter on the network interface.
2. You will need to create your own application module. Take a look/copy `UdpBasicApp` and modify it according to your needs. Check the `sendPacket()` function which creates an `ApplicationPacket`. `ApplicationPacket` contains only a single sequence number, but you can create your own application level data structure and use that for sending.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I am trying what you said, if I figure everything out I will post the code somewhere for others too.

Comment: You are welcome. As you are now on stack overflow. You are supposed to accept the answer if it solves your issue. This is for future users to see the proper answer to a question.

Comment: Okey I figured out how to do it. The code and the explanation can be found on github: https://github.com/Jamie-Wubben/omnetWireless